# Simple Linear Regression Error - fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'

Tags: python, regression, data-science, spyder

I'm currently trying to run a simple linear regression code in Spyder however it's throwing an error. I do not understand what am I doing wrong?

The error: `fit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'`.

The error is prompted when running the following code: `Y_Pred = regressor.fit(X_test)`.
[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev4LF.png).

Comment: Please post code, not pictures.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] as text in your question.

Comment: Hi Guys, Sorry, my query is resolved now. I was wrong. Since I already fitted my data on X_train and Y_train, all I had to do was predict X_Test values by running the following code Y_Pred = regressor.predict(X_Test).

Comment: This is just a reminder that, if your question was answered by @siddhartha below, make sure you accept it. People get credit for their answers, and you get to recognize the person that helped!

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to do a prediction hence you would use

```
Y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

The regressor.fit() command is used to build the model, or "insert data" into your machine learning algorithm so it will learn how to react when data is given. The predict function is used so that machine learning model will apply what it has learned, without changing anything it has already learned.